# How can I convert a vector of pointers to a linked list in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, linked-list

I'm having some trouble understanding linked lists. Everything I seen online seems to tell me different things. I have a vector of pointers to movie objects declared as:

```
vector<Movie*> movies;
```

I would like to convert this into a linked list of movie objects. Here is my MovieNode class:

```
#ifndef _MovieNode_h_
#define _MovieNode_h_

#include "Movie.h"

class MovieNode{
public:
    Movie movieData;
    MovieNode* nextMovie;
};

#endif
```

If anyone could help me out, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: you should use std::list<Movie*> movies; unless you have a very very good reason to roll-your-own linked-list class.

Comment: Why do you need a linked list? What's wrong with accessing your vector? You didn't tell what are you going to do with this vector/list and/or what's the problem you are experiencing currently.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `std::copy` STL algorithm to copy your `vector` to an `std::list` :

```
std::list<Movie*> list_movies;
std::copy( movies.begin(), movies.end(), std::back_inserter( list_movies) );
```

Or

```
std::list<Movie*> list_movies(movies.begin(), movies.end());
```

**EDIT :**

If you have a C++11 compiler, consider `std::forward_list` [as a possible alternative](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) to std::list.

Comment: You could just use the constructor: `std::list<Movie*> list_movies(movies.begin(), movies.end());`

Comment: I believe [std::list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) is different from [linked lists](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/LACRko23/).

Comment: @Benjamin: absolutely, do you want me to edit or do you add an answer ?

Comment: @user3705267 : std::list is a doubly linked list, so it is a linked list (your link explicits this)

Comment: @user3705267 : did this answers your question?

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer (click on the check mark at the left of the answer), thank you.